# How to use String.charCodeAt(); to get and store char code values of each letter of a string at once and store them?

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher

Here is my code for getting char code values for first letter of the string,then converting that char code value to minus 13(I need to do this in my question). Then I convert that char code to get the character.As far now I am able to do it for first or any character in the given input string.But what I want to do is to get char code for each letter in string all at once and then decrement each char code by 13,then convert each char code back to a letter and output the whole converted string.And also my input is NOT fixed,there are many test cases which keep changing.Please help me solve it keeping these points in mind.Here my code:

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG! It is just a useless comment.

var a=str.charCodeAt(0);//I am able to  get char code of 0 or any other  index but just one at a tim,how to do it for all the index values?
a-=13;//I need to decrement eaach char code by 13

var b=String.fromCharCode(a);//and from each char code I need to give back aletter but I want to return a whole converted string back as ouput not just a single converted letter.How to do it?
return b;
}
// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop across all the characters of the string, then keep on appending the changed value to string `b`, like this:

```js
function rot13(s)
 {
    return (s ? s : this).split('').map(function(_)
     {
        if (!_.match(/[A-Za-z]/)) return _;
        c = Math.floor(_.charCodeAt(0) / 97);
        k = (_.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 83) % 26 || 26;
        return String.fromCharCode(k + ((c == 0) ? 64 : 96));
     }).join('');
 }

alert(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Comment: I need the output FREE CODE CAMP but I am getting a little different output by your way.I sit because of any non-alphabetic character (i.e. spaces, punctuation).How to pass them without transforming them?

Comment: No w I am getting the output  F8EE C5DE CAM6 but I need the output FREE CODE CAMP.

Comment: Also there is condition :     All letters will be uppercase. Do not transform any non-alphabetic character (i.e. spaces, punctuation), but do pass them on.   That means space or any non-alphabetic character should not be changed,it should remain as it is in the output.For eg. rot13("SERR CVMMN!") should decode to "FREE PIZZA!"  and  rot13("GUR DHVPX OEBJA QBT WHZCRQ BIRE GUR YNML SBK.") should decode to "THE QUICK BROWN DOG JUMPED OVER THE LAZY FOX."

Comment: I did this in my way just addition of a line in my code.                                                                                                                             function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var b="";
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    if("A"<=str[i] && str[i]<="Z"){
  var a=str.charCodeAt(i);
      //if(65<=a<=77){
   //a+=13; 
      //}
     // else a-=13;
     a=(a-65+13)%26+65; 
 b=b+String.fromCharCode(a);
      }
    else b += str[i];
  }
 return b;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC");

Comment: // are commented code,it was removed sorry for confusion.

Comment: in the above code if (65<=a&&a<=77) will be used commented code and the code just after the comment both can work.But thanks to your code too I got another way to do it.I am new here Can I still upvote?